# filtering a data array so that it only return even index columns in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am drawing lines on a multi-line line graph. I have a data array and I need the lines to represent the even numbered indexed columns. This is what I was thinking, but I am relatively new to java and I am confused as to how to do it. Any help appreciated

```
.data(data.filter(function(d, i, a) { if (i % 2 == 0) { return a[i] ;} })
```

Comment: the function passed to `.filter` should return a boolean.

Comment: Also, removed the "Java" tag.  Despite the similarity of the names, Java and Javascript have almost no relationship.

Answer (score 1):

You are very close. The filter function must return a boolean:

`.filter(function(d, i, a) { return i % 2 = 0;})`